# MATLAB: How do I shade plot area with increasing and decreasing shades of a color

Tags: matlab, plot, area

I want to plot an area of a graph (`x = 1:24`, `y = -1:1`) with one color (black), which I then want to decrease/increase in shading in terms of the time of day. So, that I have a plot which is 'dark' in the background at night and 'light' during the day with `x` being hours of day and `y` being a data value. My sunrise would be at `6.8` and my sunset would be at `22`. I would then overlay scatter plots with data on top.

I have tried messing around with `patch` and `area` but with no luck. Here is some code I got from elsewhere on the internet but I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
% Define x, f(x), and M(x)
x = linspace(6.8, 22)';
f = sin(x)+cos(x);
M = x.^2;

% Define the vertices: the points at (x, f(x)) and (x, 0)
N = length(x);
verts = [x(:), f(:), x(:) zeros(N,1)];

% Define the faces to connect each adjacent f(x) and the corresponding points at y = 0.
q = (1:N-1)';
faces = [q, q+1, q+N+1, q+N];
p = patch('Faces', faces, 'Vertices', verts, 'FaceVertexCData', [M(:); M(:)], 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

So I want the end result to be similar to the image attached below (note faint shading - I would like the gradient stronger), but with `x = 1:24` and `y = -1:1`.

[image: shaded plot]

Comment: Could you make a manual drawing of the chart? Also you need to add sample data

Comment: Why don't you include the code you have so far and the results you're getting?

Comment: I have added some code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you ignored my request to include the results of your MATLAB code in your question, I had to look into my crystal ball to determine that your "messing around" resulted in the following error message:

> Error using patch
>
> While setting the 'Vertices' property of Patch:
>
> Value must be a 1x2 or 1x3 vector of numeric type
>
> Error in X (line 13)
>
> `p = patch('Faces', faces, 'Vertices', verts, 'FaceVertexCData', [M(:); M(:)], 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none')`

This can be resolved by concatenating the vertices vertically instead of horizontally in line 8:

```
verts = [x(:), f(:); x(:), zeros(N,1)];
```

This yields the following plot:

[image: resulting plot]

This is of course not what you want.

#### Actual Solution

You can build up your background from 5 rectangles:

```
x = [0;
     6;    % 'First daylight'
     6.8;  % Full brightness
     22;   % Beginning of 'sunset'
     22.8; % Complete darkness
     24];

vertices = [repmat(x,2,1), [ones(size(x)); -1.*ones(size(x))]];
faces = [1:5; 2:6; 8:12; 7:11].';
color = repmat([0 0 0; % 'Night' color
                0 0 0;
                1 1 1; % 'Day' color
                1 1 1;
                0 0 0;
                0 0 0],2,1);
              
patch('Faces',faces, ...
      'Vertices',vertices, ...
      'FaceVertexCData',color, ...
      'FaceColor','interp', ...
      'EdgeColor','red');
xlim([0 24]);
```

[image: bg rects]

You make the vertices of the 'night' rectangles black and the vertices of the 'day' rectangle white by assigning the appropriate RGB values to the `FaceVertexCData` property.

The color of 'sunrise'/'sunset' rectangles is then interpolated between black and white by setting the `FaceColor` property to `'interp'`.

The `EdgeColor` has only been set to `'red'` to illustrate how the background is constructed. Set the property to `'interp'` to make the lines disappear.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a pain with not showing the results, I wasn't able to access Matlab at time of writing as it was running through an extensive for loop I needed to complete first. The plot is correct in terms of the x and y axis, and the fact that there is a gradual shading. However, I would need the shape to be a rectangle (rather than a function of sin and cos), and I would need the brightest colour to be around 'midday' and the darkest at 'night'.

Comment: I have added an image close to what I would like to acheive.

Comment: @Michael Is this what you want?